# The Order of Variable and Function Definitions

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, definition, operator-precedence

Why is it that:

1. Function definitions can use definitions defined after it
2. while variable definitions can't.

For example,

a) the following **code snippet is wrong:**

```
; Must define function `f` before variable `a`.
#lang racket
(define a (f)) 
(define (f) 10)
```

b) While the following **snippet is right:**

```
; Function `g` could be defined after function `f`.
#lang racket
(define (f) (g)) ; `g` is not defined yet
(define (g) 10)
```

c) **Right** too **:**

```
; Variable `a` could be defined after function `f`
#lang racket
(define (f) a) ; `a` is not defined yet
(define a 10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know several things about Racket:

1. In Racket, each file (that starts with `#lang`) is a module, unlike many (traditional, r5rs) schemes that have no modules.
2. The scoping rules for modules are similar to the rules for a function, so in a sense, these definitions are similar to definitions in a function.
3. Racket evaluates definitions from left to right.  In scheme lingo you say that Racket's definitions have `letrec*` semantics; this is unlike some schemes that use `letrec` semantics where mutually recursive definitions never work.

So the bottom line is that the definitions are all created in the module's environment (similarly in a function, for function-local definitions), and then they are initialized from left to right.  Back-references therefore always work, so you can always do something like

```
(define a 1)
(define b (add1 a))
```

They are created in a single scope -- so in theory forward definitions are valid in the sense that they're in scope.  But actually using a value of a forward-reference is not going to work since you get a special `#<undefined>` value until the actual value is evaluated.  To see this, try to run this code:

```
#lang racket
(define (foo)
  (define a a)
  a)
(foo)
```

A module's toplevel is further restricted so that such references are actually errors, which you can see with:

```
#lang racket
(define a a)
```

Having all that in mind, things are a bit more lenient with references inside functions.  The thing is that the body of a function is not executed until the function is called -- so if a forward reference happens inside a function, it is valid (= won't get an error or `#<undefined>`) if the function is called after all of the bindings have been initialized.  This applies to plain function definitions

```
(define foo (lambda () a))
```

definitions that use the usual syntactic sugar

```
(define (foo) a)
```

and even other forms that ultimately *expand* into functions

```
(define foo (delay a))
```

With all of these, you won't get any errors by the same rule -- when all uses of the function bodies happen after the definitions were initialized.

One important note, however, is that you shouldn't confuse this kind of initialization with assignment.  This means that things like

```
(define x (+ x 1))
```

are *not* equivalent to `x = x+1` in mainstream languages.  They're more like some `var x = x+1` in a language that will fail with some "reference to uninitialized variable" error.  This is because `define` creates a *new* binding in the current scope, it does not "modify" an existing one.

Comment: how can mutual recursive definitions "never work" under usual Scheme's  `letrec`? What you mean "never"?

Comment: For "never work" -- these are value uses, see Racket's R5RS mode; yes, left-to-right usually means top-to-bottom.

Comment: so your answer is just on overly technical description of the specifics of how Racket implements what I've described in general terms.

Comment: The question was on Racket -- I explained more precisely how scope and reference work in Racket.  I don't know what would qualify as "overly technical", but regardless of the level of precision, you need to be aware that telling people that `define` is like `:=` is likely to get them confused.  In fact, getting rid of the illusion that `(define x (add1 x))` is one major milestone that imperative-minded students need to overcome when they learn racket (and other good functional languages).

Comment: I introduced pseudocode `:=` to separate the value creation *time* from the value assignment (binding) *time*. That's the image that `:=` usually evokes. I specifically told that evaluating the RHS needs all the values to be defined already,  at that point, so that would preclude the `x := x+1` problem entirely (either it's the same `x` and it's undefined, or it's a new, shadowing `x`). In short, there are no major problems with my answer.

Comment: You're collapsing two terms that are distinguished in racket: definitions and instantiations.  *Definitions* don't "happen", they are a syntactic property so they all exist throughout the code; but *instantiations* are sequential.  To see the difference, see the error `#lang racket (define a (+ 1 2)) (define + *) a`.  In any case, I'm not interested in turning this into some pissing contest, so I'll stop here.

Comment: I have no response to that, but you've told me to shut up so I guess it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an approximate general Scheme description, an analogy.

Defining a function

```
(define (f) (g))
```

is more or less like

```
f := (lambda () (g))
```

so the lambda expression is evaluated, and the resulting functional object (usually a closure) is stored in the new variable `f` being defined. The function `g` will have to be defined *when* the function `f` will be called.

Similarly, `(define (h) a)` is like `h := (lambda () a)` so only when the function `h` will be called, the reference to the variable `a` will be checked, to find its value.

But

```
(define a (f))
```

is like

```
a := (f)
```

i.e. the function `f` has to be called with no arguments, and the result of that call stored in the new variable `a` being defined. So the function has to be defined already, at that point.

Each definition in a file is executed in sequence, one after another. Each definition is allowed to refer to any of the variables being defined in a file, both above and below it <sub>(they are all said to belong to the same *scope*)</sub>, but it is allowed to use *values* of only those variables that are defined above it.

<sup>(there is an ambiguity here: imagine you were using a *built-in* function, say with `(define a (+ 1 2))`, but were also defining it later on in the file, say `(define + -)`. Is it a definition, or a redefinition? In the first case, **which is Racket's choice**, use before definition is forbidden. In the second, the "global" value is used in calculating the value of `a`, and then the function is redefined. Some Schemes may go that route. Thanks go  to Eli Barzilay for showing this to me, and to Chris Jester-Young for helping out).</sup>

Comment: This answer also has some issues, some similar to Valentin's answer (closures are irrelevant, the issues here are scope and evaluation).  Two notable problems: you should avoid comparing `define` in Racket (and other Schemes) to assignment -- they are **very** different.  Another glaring problem is that the "sequential" order of definitions is not relevant (eg, some schemes forbid backreferences too), and not always true (eg, when there are syntax definitions).  Besides, Racket's module are a kind of a "closed world" scope to avoid some of the issues with REPL-style sequential evaluation.

Comment: did you mean *forward* references can be forbidden in some Schemes? re closures: I could've said "functional objects", it's irrelevant; I never said them being closures has any relevance; I had to use *some* name. Re assignment, the functional object is defined and the binding in the environment gets it as the value. Which is what I meant by `:=`; again, irrelevant detail; *timing* is relevant. Apparently the evaluation model that I used *is* what's going on here; it *could*'ve been that whole file is processed 1st so `(define a (f))` works; then the OP wouldn't have had to ask their question.

Comment: @EliBarzilay and, there were no syntax definitions mentioned in teh Q.

Comment: Yes, forward references can be forbidden, but the fact that backward ones are is more interesting (try `#lang r5rs` in racket to see it); closures are not important since you can have other evaluation implementation -- a very known one is the "substitution model" where there are no closures but scope is still the same; timing is relevant in a weird sense since Scheme is generally trying to avoid it; and finally the question was about *scope* and identifier references -- and all of that is very much syntax!

Comment: For the 2nd time, I never said closures are important. -- moving goalposts alert: first mentioning *syntax definitions* specifically  and then talking about syntax in general -- timing is everything: [*"and each id is set immediately after the corresponding val-expr is evaluated"*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html). -- if forward references are forbidden then no modular programming is possible. (? we never talked about REPLs, at least I wasn't; if some REPLs forbid forward refs, is not in the scope of this question)

Comment: @EliBarzilay similarly, if backwards refs are forbidden, we couldn't use any of the functions defined above or elsewhere.

Comment: For no forward refs, see (oca)ml; re your reference to the racket manual, that's the wrong place -- look further down the page at `letrec` which is the relevant thing here, there is still an "immediately" there, of course, but note the differences from `let`; REPL is only in the context of why Racket chose to diverge from traditional r5rs toplevel with different scoping rules; and re backward refs, try this in Racket: `#lang r5rs (define (foo) (define a 1) (define b a) b)` and see what `(foo)` returns.

Comment: @EliBarzilay that's where I copied the citation from. the entry for letrec.

Comment: What I meant is to compare the `let` description with that of `letrec`; see also the difference between `letrec` and `letrec*` in r6rs.

Comment: I don't care for r6rs here; I've already compared Racket's let and letrec, and I know how it works in r5rs.

Comment: Racket's internal definitions use its `letrec` which is similar to r6rs's `letrec*` -- unlike many schemes that use r6rs's `letrec` for internal definitions.

Comment: Why  do I need to concern myself with r6rs's letrec, if I already have documentation for Racket's letrec?

Comment: Because the difference between them will be enlightening.  But again, I'll stop here since this is turning into some weird pissing contest.