# Is there a way to disable function-hoisting in Racket?

Tags: racket, hoisting

I'm using Racket to teach (functional) programming, and I really like the way features are disabled for beginnings students. One problem however I'm having with Racket is the fact that functions seem to be hoisted even in the most restricted version. Now is there a way to disable function hoisting in racket so that the following code would produce an error?

```
(define (f x)
  (g x)
)

(check-expect (f 3) 3)

(define (g x)
  x
)
```

Comment: This isn't really quite 'hoisting'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Order of Variable and Function Definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654973/the-order-of-variable-and-function-definitions)

Comment: I think the answer is `no`. There is no option for turning this into an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is not caused by hoisting functions. It is caused by `check-expect`. You can think of `check-expect` as being "hoisted downwards."

If you replace `check-expect` with your own function, you get the normal error:

```
g is used here before its definition
```

For the program:

```
(define (my-check-expect actual expected) ....)

(define (f x)
  (g x))

(my-check-expect (f 3) 3)

(define (g x)
  x)
```

If you want the students to only write tests after they code, you can make a teachpack that provides a new version of `check-expect`.

However, this is a bad idea. The Design Recipe teaches students to write functional examples/tests before they code. This special behavior of `check-expect` is what allows them to do that.

Comment: I know, that eventually this is a good habit to develop, but I've noticed, that errors are what helps students lern best... It's only one week before I'll explain hoisting :)